# Make a certain sprite ignore SKPhysicsBody

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am having an issue making a sprite ignore the effects of a SKPhysicsBody placed as a ground platform in an iOS project. I have only one sprite that I would like to "follow the rules" of the SKPhysicsBody and for all other sprites to "pass through". I have searched for a way to do this, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add some code related to the Sprite node which you want to 'follow the rules' as well as for the ground platform.

Comment: You need to set the collisionBitMasks properly in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for any physics body that you want to pass through set its  collisionBitMask to 0 that means that it won't collide with anything, make sure you don't set the collisionBitMask of the ground to the type of sprite you want them to pass through,